# How to read the I-sam files created bu Sungard's Omniplus system usning java. Omni Script is slow

Tags: java, unix, cgi, omnipay, isam

I am working on Sungard's Omniplus- Omni Web solution OWS 8.0, that's using OmniScript services to read/write the data in the I-sam files in Unix-AIX.
Since it's COBOL based old processing system it's processing is too slow.

Is there any way I can read those I-sam files using Java/Perl so that I can build my CGI website with faster response?

Comment: Yes, but if you expect a bit more detail in an answer, you should provide more details in your question like the format of the file, and how it should be processed.

Comment: Hotzst- Format of the file is ISAM(Indexed Sequential Access Method) similar like VSAM in mainframe. It's used by COBOL heavily. As long as processing is concern I'll just read it by supplying the key parameter and take the part of string required for my reporting purpose, rest business logic will be in java and front end could be in CGI or JSP.